# How to override page.tpl.php with view's template file

Tags: views, theming

I am using D7 and view3 (beta). I created a view named employee with a template for the field first_image, **views-view-field--employee--page--field-first_image.tpl.php**. When I rescan the theme information, this template became bold. It worked fine (When clicking the image, a slim box will show).

But I inserted this view in a basic page using insert view2.x dev module with tag **[view:employee]**. But this time my template file doesn't show and seems to be broken. How can I solve this?

Comment: Hello, there is no a grid template? are you using a custom grid template?. Also, seems that you can fix some CSS rules to fix your issue.

Comment: I am using unformatted list format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you define a specific display in your template: views-view-field--employee--**page**--field-first_image.tpl.php.

Then you don't specify a display in your insert tag, making it fallback to *default*.

To fix your problem you need to either strip the display part of your template name or specify a display in your tag, like [view:employee=page].

I would probably go for the first solution, so your theming targets all possible displays of that view, but how you do it really depends on your implementation.

Comment: It worked for me!! Thanks a lot Tobias Sjösten... :) :)